# Can I combine fields via Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dynamic-data

I'm new to Linq to Sql, what I would like to achieve is to create a single read only property on the Entity class that is a combination of multiple fields, specifically I want to create a name field that combines- title, forename and surname.

I can see how to do it by changing the .designer.cs file but know I'm not supposed to touch that.

I'm attempting to do this so that in dynamic data I get a single column rather than multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info re `[ScaffoldColumn(true)]`; I'll file that away for next time ;-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to use a `partial class`; create a new .cs file, and **in the same namespace** add a new class named for your type:

```
namespace My.Data.Namespace {
    partial class Employee {
        public string Foo {
            get {return Forename + " " + Surname; } // etc
        }
    }
}
```

This *combines with* the original (generated) class file. This is a common approach for adding additional functionality into generated entities (including the data-context). You might also want to look at "partial methods", since a number of partial methods are defined and used by LINQ-to-SQL.

One caveat: if your dbml is called `MySystem.dbml`, then **avoid** creating a `MySystem.cs` file (presumably for your partial classes); there is a bug in the code-generator that can cause this to fail. Just name it something else.

Comment: I've done that but in Dynamic data not seeing it appear in the grid that is constructed, Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know. If the property is available from your *other* code, then I wonder whether dynamic data is looking at the meta-model (rather than the type's properties). In which case it would be very hard to get it working. It might also simply be that dynamic data wants read/write properties... I don't know.

Comment: Found the answer.  I needed to add [ScaffoldColumn(true)] attribute and now it appears in the grid. Lovely

Answer (score 0):

in your LINQ select statement, why don't you use something like:

```
select new {FullName = x.FirstName + " " + x.Surname};
```

Not sure if the syntax is 100% there but check out the idea.